# Intl.supportedValuesOf Property 'supportedValuesOf' does not exist on type 'typeof Intl'

Tags: typescript

I'm using dayJS as my date-time library and want to present a list of all time zones.
I tried the use of the Intl object:
`Intl.supportedValuesOf("timeZone")`
but I'm getting a typescript error:
`TS2339: Property 'supportedValuesOf' does not exist on type 'typeof Intl'.`
I can get the values but I want to avoid using the @ts-ignore notation

How can I add the updated types for the Intl object?

Comment: What lib are you targeting in your tsconfig

Comment: Do you mean in the compilerOptions? if so "target": "es5",

Comment: There’s also a libs option

Comment: here:  "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"]

Comment: Same problem. Visual Studio code is looking at the wrong lib. Can't figure out how to get it to look at the correct one as it exists in the .vscode directory

Answer (score 5):

See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49231

"the change doesn't ship until Typescript 5.1"

Comment: To add to this, see [the suggested temporary solution](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49231#issuecomment-1137251612).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue as well. I will elaborate on the answers already provided.

If you want to access the method `Intl.supportedValuesOf()` on Typescript versions prior to Typescript 5.1, you can create a file `Intl.d.ts` (I think the name is actually arbitrary) and copy the below into the file:

```js
declare namespace Intl {
  type Key = "calendar" | "collation" | "currency" | "numberingSystem" | "timeZone" | "unit";

  function supportedValuesOf(input: Key): string[];
}
```

Then, in the tsconfig.json file, add the relative path to the `Intl.d.ts` file we just created in the "include" property, like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": ["/types/Intl.d.ts"]
}
```

You may have to restart your application to see the changes